# I am not able to build my project using ng build --prod

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

I have finished my project using Angular 6 and would like to deploy my project, however whenever I run `ng build --prod` it comes up with these errors, any other command such as `npm start`, `ng serve` or `ng build` they run successfully.

```
ERROR in src/app/signup/signup.component.html(77,78): Property 'customLoadingTemplate' does not 
exist on type 'SignupComponent'.
src/app/signin/signin.component.html(48,78): Property 'customLoadingTemplate' does not exist on type 
'SigninComponent'.
src/app/questionseven/questionseven.component.html(15,41): Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
src/app/addemployee/addemployee.component.html(157,78): Property 'customLoadingTemplate' does not 
exist on type 'AddemployeeComponent'.
src/app/editemployee/editemployee.component.html(164,78): Property 'customLoadingTemplate' does not 
exist on type 'EditemployeeComponent'.
src/app/editemployee/editemployee.component.html(311,53): Property 'buttonDisabled' does not exist 
on type 'EditemployeeComponent'.
src/app/editemployee/editemployee.component.html(322,50): Property 'buttonDisabled' does not exist 
on type 'EditemployeeComponent'.
src/app/editemployee/editemployee.component.html(332,11): Property 'buttonDisabled' does not exist 
on type 'EditemployeeComponent'.
src/app/editemployee/editemployee.component.html(15,24): Property 'personalInfo' does not exist on 
type 'EditemployeeComponent'.
src/app/editemployee/editemployee.component.html(173,54): Property 'PersonalInfoClicked' does not 
exist on type 'EditemployeeComponent'.
src/app/employees/employees.component.html(91,80): Property 'customLoadingTemplate' does not exist 
on type 'EmployeesComponent'.
src/app/employeeposition/employeeposition.component.html(136,74): Property 'customLoadingTemplate' 
does not exist on type 'EmployeepositionComponent'.
src/app/employeedepartment/employeedepartment.component.html(135,76): Property 
'customLoadingTemplate' does not exist on type 'EmployeedepartmentComponent'.
src/app/banks/banks.component.html(136,76): Property 'customLoadingTemplate' does not exist on type 
'BanksComponent'.
```

Comment: You have a lot of explicit error that you need to solve. This is nothing generic that you can google from a blog. You need to solve all your errors to be able to build for production.  Most likely all these properties that are missing need to be made optional or removed if they are not used.

Comment: That was exactly the case, and since that it is a comment not an answer I would have marked it as the correct answer, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Declare all the variable which i used in the HTML with public access specifier

```
E.g,
public customLoadingTemplate: any;
public buttonDisabled: any;
```

Answer (score -1):

We Have to opt-out of type checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks. To do so, we label these with the `any` type or you can create class or interface to avoid it

So give type `any` to the properties

```
customLoadingTemplate: any;
personalInfo: any;
```

and all pending properties

src/app/questionseven/questionseven.component.html(15,41): Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

There is a function who have Expected 1 argument but you have pass just 0 argument check that one

Comment: I think your answer is correct and I have upvoted it